# Error while installing robotframework-ride

Tags: python, robotframework

i cant able to install pip install robotframework-ride,getting error ,
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

installed robot frame work using pip and downloaded wxpython and installed at g drive in python folder for my convinence,kindly give solution friends

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if RIDE is still that bad editor as it was two years ago - but I would recommend to use something else. Check out VS Code and its RF support plugins, they are really worth it.

Comment: @LubosJerabek Can you give details of what version of RIDE and operating system, you had a bad experience? Would like to see if those problems are gone.

Comment: @Helio I think I was running Windows 10...and it could be two years ago approximately? I remember the stop button never worked when I wanted to kill my tests, it was loading very slowly (2 minutes to open the project) and it wasn't helping the test development at all (no intellisense and no tabs.) VS Code does all of these things.

Comment: Well, RIDE exists since 2008, and it has keywords selection, but not autocomplete. Sometimes the tests using certain libraries don't react too well to the Stop signal (and this is also an operating system limitation). Big projects, especially in many folder trees or files, takes more time to load. Of course that RIDE is not comparable to the New Kid on the Block, VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

Because Python 3.9 is recent, some libraries, applications or modules are not compatible with it, or even tested. This is the case of RIDE that is having a Beta version compatible with Python 3.8, but not tested on Python 3.9.

The project page of RIDE is [here](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE).

About the error you found, it happened because your system is trying to build wxPython 4.0.7.post2 because there is no package for Python 3.9. Not even for version 4.1.1, exists a released package.

The project page of wxPython is [here](https://wxpython.org/).